# Proper use of NET 5 csproj properties Platform and Platforms

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

This question is about NET 5 csproj file properties `<Platform>, <Platforms>, and <PlatformTarget>`.

The "msbuild clean" target references different project folders dependending on the content of the csproj XML properties.

Msbuild clean using `<Platform>x64</Platform>` (singular Platform) correctly deletes files from

```
Deleting file "C:\dev\myproject\bin\x64\Debug\net5.0-windows7.0\myproject.exe".
```

Msbuild clean using `<Platforms>x64</Platforms>` (plural Platform) wrongly? deletes files from

```
Deleting file "C:\dev\myproject\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows7.0\myproject.exe".
```

Msbuild clean using `<Platform>x64;AnyCPU</Platform>` (singular Platform) correctly deletes files from

```
Deleting file "C:\dev\myproject\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows7.0\myproject.exe"
but fails to delete files from the x64 output folder like so:
Deleting file "C:\dev\myproject\bin\x64\Debug\net5.0-windows7.0\myproject.exe".
```

Msbuild clean using `<Platforms>x64;AnyCPU</Platforms>` (plural Platform) correctly deletes files from

```
Deleting file "C:\dev\myproject\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows7.0\myproject.exe"
but fails to delete files from the x64 output folder like so:
Deleting file "C:\dev\myproject\bin\x64\Debug\net5.0-windows7.0\myproject.exe".
```

Is this correct behavior? I expected the clean target to delete files from the output folders associated with each platform in the `<Platform>` property.

Why does plural version of Platforms always default to AnyCPU behavior for the 'clean' target regardless of the property value? Platform can be used for a single platform, but Platforms is required for multiple platforms. My experiments above show that only singular Platform has the expected (intuitive) behavior.

Am I missing something obvious or am I expecting the wrong behavior? What are the precise rules for when I should use Platform and Platforms?

(I have even seen PlatformTarget in some online project files/examples, but maybe PlatformTarget is a custom property and not an MSBuild-defined property?)

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation please

Comment: @stuartd, not sure what documentation you are referring to. Guessing PlatformTarget? Here's a Microsoft link that shows it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-target-framework-and-target-platform?view=vs-2022

Comment: This link will also help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004901/msbuild-cli-platform-x64-and-project-file-property-platformx64-platform-give/71038391